# issue with python about win32api.SetConsoleCtrlHandler

Tags: python, winapi, cmd

Today when I use win32api.SetConsoleCtrlHandler to catch close button of console window.

code like:

```py
import os
import sys
import win32api

if __name__ == "__main__":
    def callback(sig):
        print("Exit handler called!")
        exit_fun()
        sys.exit(0)

    def exit_fun():
        input("Press any key to exit!")

    win32api.SetConsoleCtrlHandler(callback, True)

    print("Press to quit")
    try:
        input()
    except (EOFError):
        while 1:
            pass
```

I have a question with exit_fun funtion,when I use ctrl c to close cmd window, it's work!

But! I try to use close button of console window. the exit_fun is doesn't work.

I don't know WHY...

Thanks for your answer : )

Comment: Closing the console window terminates the console process. It doesn't retroactively inject a control sequence. Though it's unclear from the question, what issue you need to have resolved. *"It doesn't work"* simply isn't a problem statement. [ask] explains how to do better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But! I try to use close button of console window. the exit_fun is
> doesn't work.

I assume that you are talking about why the `exit_fun` can't read console input anymore.

When you click the close button of the console window, the system generates `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT` signal. **Console functions**, or any C run-time functions that call console functions, **may not work** reliably during processing this signal mentioned previously. **The reason is that some or all of the internal console cleanup routines may have been called before executing the process signal handler.**

And there is a timeout (5000ms) after you click the close button. The console process will exit when timeout happens even if you do nothing. However, there is no timeout when using ctrl c.

Refer to [`SetConsoleCtrlHandler` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolectrlhandler#remarks) and [`HandlerRoutine` callback function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/handlerroutine#timeouts).

Comment: Original！ Thank you for your answer！

Comment: Hello Rita. I'm trying to use `win32api.SetConsoleCtrlHandler` to close an Excel instance if the console application gets interrupted/closed mid executing. The function does get called but I get an error when I try to close which normally wouldn't happen outside of it, maybe because it's a different thread but I'm not sure. I would appreciate it if you would try to help me. [Link to my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63037454/how-to-close-an-excel-instance-if-the-python-console-program-gets-interrupted-an). Thank you for your time.